# Display NA in excel output from R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, numeric, na

I have a dataframe which is numeric but I want the blanks to be NA and for this to be shown in the excel output. My file is CSV which reads in as numeric with 2 columns. My code being used is below. When I export the data now the cells are displaying #NUM!. Any advice would be helpful.

```
#read in data files for count#
data = read.csv("data.csv", na.strings=c("..","x","NA"))# read   csv     file 
latest = read.csv("Latest.csv", na.strings=c("..","x","NA"))# read     csv file 

"Merge both data sets which are all the data and the latest quarter"
total <- merge(data,latest,by="Group", sort=FALSE)

#create excel output
wb = createWorkbook(type="xlsx")

countsheet = createSheet(wb, "count")

xlsx.addTitle<-function(sheet, rowIndex, title, titleStyle){
rows <-createRow(sheet,rowIndex=rowIndex)
sheetTitle <-createCell(rows, colIndex=1)
setCellValue(sheetTitle[[1,1]], title)
setCellStyle(sheetTitle[[1,1]], titleStyle)
}
TITLE_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb)+ Font(wb,  heightInPoints=16, 
                        color="blue", isBold=TRUE, underline=0)

xlsx.addTitle(countsheet, rowIndex=1, title="count",titleStyle =   TITLE_STYLE)
addDataFrame(total, countsheet, startRow =3, row.names=FALSE, showNA=TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "data_Level.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please include sample data (a subset of the dataframe "total" would work) for people looking to answer your question. Also specify which package you're using (xlsxconnect?).

Comment: I am using xlsx for the excel output.  sample <- matrix( c(1,2,3,4,5,0), nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow=FALSE)

Comment: If you don't mind everything being turned into a string before being exported: total[is.na(total)] = "NA" should work.

Comment: If I do that then the excel file will be string's, so I can't highlight a few cells in excel to get the total of them I excel ? is that right?

Comment: Why not just have showNA=FALSE, then? This will output a blank cell in your excel file where an NA exists in the dataframe. If you really want to include the NAs as NAs, you'll have to do some work to format the cells which correspond to NAs to be text cells and everything else to be numeric cells.

Comment: Yeah I want to have NA displayed in my output and not a blank. is there a way to find the blank cells and make them NA string only and not the whole column?

Comment: Not that I know of within R, columns must always be of a single class as far as I'm aware. Why do you need the NAs to appear as NAs instead of blanks in the workbook? Is this behaviour definitely necessary?

Comment: The data isn't missing it's "Not applicable" so it shouldn't be blank as such.

Comment: Is there other data which is missing which you intend to have as blanks? If not, I would just proceed with the "blanks" assuming to be data which is not applicable.